# How to use Gujarati calendar in iphone?

Tags: ios, nscalendar

I want this type of calendar in my app. How to fetch these **Gujarati** **tithi** from the date or from the native library? Thanks for the help.[image: Gujarati Calendar]

Comment: based on the display it's from the custom library so you should check for the label which is set in the calendar

Comment: I have check every third party, but I didn't got any library that has this features in it.

Comment: so are you saying this display comes from the native calendar? i didn't seen like this display in native calendar

Comment: yes see this app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/haridham-calendar/id979060287?ls=1&mt=8

Comment: ok , native calendar is not providing is mostly not providing this, you may find some api which may return you the tithi's for selected date

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any resources to get `tithi` but this PDF file might help you to calculate on your own:

http://www.tifr.res.in/~vahia/tithi-calculations.pdf

Putting a sample formula here just in case:

```
tithi(DOY) = longitude of Moon – Longitude of Sun (of the orbit of 360o)
```

Comment: But I want the solution from the native app. see this app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/haridham-calendar/id979060287?ls=1&mt=8